# How to read data from firebase realtime database to Dialogflow

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

I am new to this, I wanted to know how to read data from firebase realtime database to dialogflow. I want to compare DNI(id) and get the information from that table that only that DNI(id) has.

This is my code:

```
      function askReunion(agent)
      {
      const dni = agent.parameters.dni ; 
        agent.add(`Wait a minute...`);
          return admin.database().ref('reunion').once("value").then((snapshot) => {
            var dniBd = snapshot.child("dni").val();
            if( dni == dniBd){
              agent.add(`here I will put the information of the dni ` );
            }
            else{
              agent.add(`You dont have any appointment. ` );
            }
          });
      }
```

This is the table where I want to read the results:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your call to `once('value')` is fetching a snapshot of the "reunion" object from the database. All the children of this object have names such as "-M84_ViEcYi0UzQifWhq".

*But* you are then checking for a child named "dhq", and there is no child with this name. *Each* child does have a property with this name, but that isn't what your code is getting.

Instead of doing a reference fetch, it sounds like you might want to do a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries) against attributes of each of the children. Assuming "dni" is unique, this might look something like this:

```
const ref = admin.database().ref('reunion');
return ref.orderBy("dni").equalTo( dni ).once("value").then( snapshot => {
  if( snapshot.exists() ){
    agent.add( "Ok, I found your record." );
  } else {
    agent.add( "I don't have any record of that." );
  }
});
```